# Which unix utility can help me extract specific characters from a line in the file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a file f1 containing following data:

```
---
sc_swVersion_t isaPDAVersion = {0,4,0,0,0,34};
---
```

from this I want to extract the first 4 characters after the opening brace. Can some one please advise what unix utility/shell command can do that. Say:

```
cat f1 | grep isaPDAVersion | < Some utility> gives me 0400
```

Comment: The 'first four characters after the opening brace' are `0,4,`; you said you wanted `0400`.  What counts as a 'character'?

Comment: If you're ever `cat`ing to `grep` you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Evan : Whats wrong in cat and grep

Comment: @Karun grep takes a filename argument. `grep isaPDAVersion f1` is the same as `cat f1 | grep isaPDAVersion` except the former is more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep isaPDAVersion f1 | awk -F\{ '{print $2}'| awk -F, '{print $1$2$3$4}'
```

or more simply in gawk

```
gawk  '/isaPDAVersion/ {match($4,"([[:digit:]]),([[:digit:]]),([[:digit:]]),([[:digit:]])",a); {print a[1]a[2]a[3]a[4]}}' f1
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a ton Smith :) I was breaking my head with sed to achieve it. Is there a thumb rule where one can apply sed and where awk.

Comment: Strange, when I run this (with `$1`), I get `sc_swVersion_t isaPDAVersion = {0400` with both `mawk` and `gawk`. Which version do you use?

Comment: There was an edit by another user that added the $1.  I've fixed it.

Comment: what's the alternate way than to using cat?

Comment: awk and sed both take filenames as arguments, you don't have to pipe to them.

Comment: @JoshuaSmith's comment: _Most_ Unix commands take either standard input (via a pipe or <) or arbitrary lists of files as input. Part of the whole "toolbox of filters that can be connected arbitrarily" idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with sed, e.g.

```
cat f1 | sed -ne "s/^.*isaPDAVersion[^{]*{\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\).*$/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[^{]*{//;       # discard up to and including the first {
     s/,//g;           # discard the commas
     s/\(....\).*/\1/  # get the first four characters, discard the rest
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
echo "sc_swVersion_t isaPDAVersion = {0,4,0,0,0,34};" | cut -f2 -d\{ | cut -f1-4 -d, | tr -d ,
```

Replace the echo with a "cat filename" and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Yuck. Just use Perl.

```
perl -nE's/\D//g,print for@{[split/,/]}[0..3]'
```

^ No scrolling needed.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/{/s/^.*{\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\).*$/\1\2\3\4/p' f1
```

Answer (score -1):

GNU awk

```
gawk '
  match($0, /isaPDAVersion.*\{([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),/, a) {
    printf("%s%s%s%s\n", a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4])
  }
' f1
```